Changing URL Parameters for Taxonomy in WordPress
I have two taxonomies: Genres and Occasions. I want to have my parameters "translated" and treated the same as my original parameters. Currently, it only responds the correct way to parameters like ?tax-genre= and ?tax-occasion=.
I use this function to translate the parameters:
public function translate_taxonomy_params() {
    $translated = [];

    if (isset($_REQUEST['genre'])) {
        if (is_array($_REQUEST['genre'])) {
            $translated['tax-genre'] = $_REQUEST['genre'];
        } else {
            $translated['tax-genre'] = [$_REQUEST['genre']];
        }
        unset($_REQUEST['genre']);
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['occasion'])) {
        if (is_array($_REQUEST['occasion'])) {
            $translated['tax-occasion'] = $_REQUEST['occasion'];
        } else {
            $translated['tax-occasion'] = [$_REQUEST['occasion']];
        }
        unset($_REQUEST['occasion']);
    }

    return array_merge($_REQUEST, $translated);
}

While this works for retrieving the correct posts on archive pages, it does not set the right checkboxes in the filter sidebar, despite my tax query being set correctly:
 [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [taxonomy] => genre
                    [field] => slug
                    [terms] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => thriller
                        )
                )
    )

My question is, how can I make the URL parameters behave the same way as the original parameters? Specifically, how can ?genre=thriller be interpreted in the backend as ?tax-genre=thriller, on every page/function?
I'm using AJAX to filter results and dynamically updating the URL with jQuery so that if a visitor opens a post, they can easily return to their previous filtered results. However, the prefix "tax-" feels less user-friendly.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
